# trying to use the basic tutorial for ogre in code::blocks produces undefined references to '__unwind_resume' and '__gxx_personality_v0'

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, ogre

When following [this](https://wiki.ogre3d.org/tiki-index.php?page=Setting%20Up%20An%20Application%20-%20CodeBlocks#Setting_up_Code::Blocks_MinGW_for_OGRE_Development) tutorial I'm getting the following errors: undefined reference to '__unwind_resume' and undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'

The file producing these undefined reference error's is libboost_system-mgw47-mt-1_51.a. I have already tried the following fixes to no avail:

1. Forcing Code::blocks to use g++ instead of gcc.
   Result: No change
2. Adding-lstdc++ to the list of libraries the linker links to.
   Result: 39 more errors in addition to the __unwind_resume and __gxx_personality_v0 undefined reference errors.
   [image: image1]
3. Installing the latest MingW and pointing my compiler to use it instead of its own version
   Result: Compiler errors now exceeds max value :(
   [image2 http://s24.postimage.org/3u6tik4dh/moreerrors2.jpg](http://s24.postimage.org/3u6tik4dh/moreerrors2.jpg)

Any help troubleshooting these errors is appreciated, I really want to get this thing working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found part of the solution, I got the compiler to create an executable file, but it currently throws OGRE::filenotfoundexception and terminates. I did this by downloading boost_1_53_0 and building libboost_system-mgw47-mt-1-53.a and linking to that instead of the other one, then it gave me the error on startup "the procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll." So to work around that I went to orwell's mingw folder and found that libstdc++-6.dll in that folder was around 800 KB in size and the one codeblocks was using was 5 mb, I switched them out to see if it worked and it got the executable running now but it throws said exception and terminates.

EDIT1: Strangely enough simply adding a blank file called resources.cfg (the file that caused the exception) causes the program to run but now an Ogre windows appears asking for a rendering system

EDIT2: After realizing I'm supposed to copy everything from ogre's bin/release directory to my executable files directory (and the media directory to 2 folders up from my executables directory) I did that and everything finally worked perfectly!